# How do I preview images smaller in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I've tried `#+ATTR_ORG: :width 100`, perhaps that only works on file urls, not internet urls?

My code:

```
#+ATTR_ORG: :width 100
[[https://thumbnails-visually.netdna-ssl.com/different-types-of-beer-beer-101_5617d03b3d778_w1500.png]]
```

I'm on Doom Emacs, 27, if that matters! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the value of `org-image-actual-width`? If it is t (the default) org-mode will display images using their original width. If set to nil it should use the attribute you set (there are other nuances for this variable but I defer to the docs for those).

I don't think this will work for anything other than file urls since those are the only pattern that `org-display-inline-images` will search for when creating the inline images.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's nil, I think my problem is that you can't set the width of urls, only files.